# SQLAlchemy - object "is already present in this session" when using a new session with older objects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Some context:
I have a set of tables that inherit from a base table, called `things`. `things` has a foreign key to a table called `objecttypes`. `objecttypes` provides the `polymorphic_identity` values for each of the child tables.

I'm seeing that, when I create a new session, in a certain set of cases, data from the old session isn't merged into the new session.

If I have:

```py
eastGate = Gate(name="eastGate", origin=tokyo, destinationInput=luggage, objectType=typeDict['gate'])
```

where `origin`, `destinationInput`, and `objectType` were all relationships whose objects are previously defined, I see the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't attach instance <ObjectType at 0x10592fe50>; another instance with key (
<class '__main__.ObjectType'>, (1,), None) is already present in this session.
```

There seem to be a number of instances when this could happen, but in this particular scenario, it appears to be as follows:

1. Add a new object into a new session
2. Close session and remove() from scoped_session
3. Reference the object in two newly constructed ones via their relationship
4. Error appears on the second object

```py
    # typeDict just contains a pre-fetched ObjectTypes 
    tokyo = Location(name="tokyo", objectType=typeDict['location'])
    tokyo = write(tokyo)

    # If I clear out the current session here, the error will occur
    scopedSessionFactory().close()
    scopedSessionFactory.remove()

    westGate = Gate(name="westGate", destination=tokyo, objectType=typeDict['gate'])
    westGate = write(westGate)

    luggage = LocationInput(name="luggage", objectType=typeDict['locationinput'])
    luggage = write(luggage)

    # This is the line where the error occurs
    eastGate = Gate(name="eastGate", origin=tokyo, destinationInput=luggage, objectType=typeDict['gate'])
    eastGate = write(eastGate)
```

Now that I've reproduced the issue, I'm not quite sure what the underlying cause is. I could just use the same session in this particular example, but I'd like to be able to keep some of my sessions shorter lived.

Environment:
Python: 2.7.14 (also happens on 3.7.x)
SqlAlchemy: 1.3.20

Full example below:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect, Column, Integer, String, DateTime, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, aliased, contains_eager, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class ObjectType(Base):
    __tablename__ = "objecttypes"
    id=Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "ObjectType({}, id={})".format(self.name, self.id)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine) # We'll call this again later
sessionFactory = sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False)
scopedSessionFactory = scoped_session(sessionFactory)

def startScope():
    return scopedSessionFactory()

def endScope():
    scopedSessionFactory().close()
    scopedSessionFactory.remove()
    return

def addObjectTypes():
    """
    Add in all the object types to the db without using a session
    """
    values = ["('location')", "('locationinput')", "('gate')"]
    q =  """INSERT INTO objecttypes (name) VALUES {}""".format(",".join(values))
    engine.execute(q)
    return

def buildObjectTypes():
    addObjectTypes()
    session = startScope()
    types = session.query(ObjectType).all()
    endScope()
    return dict([(objType.name, objType) for objType in types])

# Holds all the types
typeDict = buildObjectTypes()

class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = "things"
    id=Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=Column(String)
    object_type_id=Column(Integer, ForeignKey('objecttypes.id'))
    objectType=relationship(ObjectType)
    version=Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    timeCreated=Column(DateTime)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'version_id_col': version,
        'polymorphic_on':object_type_id,
        'with_polymorphic':'*',
        'polymorphic_load':'inline',
    }

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}, id={}, type={}, version={}".format(self.name, self.id, self.objectType, self.version)


class Location(Thing):
    __tablename__ = "locations"
    id=Column(Integer, ForeignKey('things.id'),primary_key=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': typeDict['location'].id
    }

class LocationInput(Thing):
    __tablename__ = "locationinputs"
    id=Column(Integer, ForeignKey('things.id'),primary_key=True)
    previousGateId=Column(Integer, ForeignKey('gates.id'))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': typeDict['locationinput'].id
    }

class Gate(Thing):
    __tablename__ = "gates"
    id=Column(Integer, ForeignKey('things.id'),primary_key=True)

    originId=Column(Integer, ForeignKey('locations.id'))
    origin=relationship(Location, foreign_keys=[originId], backref="originGates")

    originInputId=Column(Integer, ForeignKey('locationinputs.id'))
    originInput=relationship(LocationInput, foreign_keys=[originInputId], backref="originInputGates")

    destinationId=Column(Integer, ForeignKey('locations.id'))
    destination=relationship(Location, foreign_keys=[destinationId], backref="destinationGates")

    destinationInputId=Column(Integer, ForeignKey('locationinputs.id'))
    destinationInput=relationship(LocationInput, foreign_keys=[destinationInputId], backref="destinationInputGates")

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': typeDict['gate'].id
    }

LocationInput.previousGate = relationship(Gate, foreign_keys=[LocationInput.previousGateId])
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

def write(obj):
    session = scopedSessionFactory()
    return session.merge(obj)

def reproduceError():
    tokyo = Location(name="tokyo", objectType=typeDict['location'])
    tokyo = write(tokyo)

    # If I clear out the current session here, the error will occur
    scopedSessionFactory().close()
    scopedSessionFactory.remove()

    westGate = Gate(name="westGate", destination=tokyo, objectType=typeDict['gate'])
    westGate = write(westGate)

    luggage = LocationInput(name="luggage", objectType=typeDict['locationinput'])
    luggage = write(luggage)

    # This is the line where the error occurs
    eastGate = Gate(name="eastGate", origin=tokyo, destinationInput=luggage, objectType=typeDict['gate'])
    eastGate = write(eastGate)
    print(eastGate)
    return

reproduceError()
```